# creating function of function

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I'm trying to create a function of the code below, in Winforms. 
what you're seeing is a function in the form called ytplayerSearch, not ytplayer. 
Currently the code works but i've been trying to make it more clean.

```
private void btPlayMin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ytplayer.playLink(sender, e, link);
            ytplayer.miniMax("Normal", new Size(300, 24), new Size(400, 95), false, "", FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow, true);
            ytplayer.TopMost = true;
            ytplayer.BringToFront();
            ytplayer.TopMost = false;
            int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 375;
            ytplayer.Location = new Point(x, 0);
            ytplayer.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btPlayNorm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ytplayer.playLink(sender, e, link);
            ytplayer.miniMax("Minimal", new Size(300, 240), new Size(400,335), true, "YoutubePlayer", FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle, false); 
            ytplayer.TopMost = true;
            ytplayer.BringToFront();
            ytplayer.TopMost = false;
            ytplayer.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

The problem is I don't quite know how to send a function to another function. The lower code might make my problem a bit more clear.

```
private void settingsYTP(.....problem.....)
{
}
```

Comment: move to parameters all different settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand right you need something like this

```
private void btPlayMin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settingsYTP(sender, e, link, "Normal", new Size(300, 24), new Size(400, 95), false, "", FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow, true);
    int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 375;
    ytplayer.Location = new Point(x, 0);
    ytplayer.Show();
    this.Close();
}

private void btPlayNorm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settingsYTP(sender, e, link, "Minimal", new Size(300, 240), new Size(400,335), true, "YoutubePlayer", FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle, false);
    ytplayer.Show();
    this.Close();
}

private void settingsYTP(object sender, EventArgs e, string link, string minmax,Size size1, Size size2, bool b1, string text,FormBorderStyle bs, bool b2)
{
    ytplayer.playLink(sender, e, link);
    ytplayer.miniMax(minmax, size1, size2, b1, text, bs, b2); 
    ytplayer.TopMost = true;
    ytplayer.BringToFront();
    ytplayer.TopMost = false;
}
```

Comment: perfect, this is exactly it

Comment: @Bjorn9000 also see more about `refactoring: Extract methods`

Comment: well almost perfect, needed this to work perfectly `ytplayer.playLink( sender,  e, link);` then add the right variables to the call `settingsYTP(sender,e,link,"Minimal", new Size(300, 240), new Size(400,335), true, "YoutubePlayer", FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle, false);`     as you see it lacked the object and sender obviously. Great help @Grundy

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegates as proposed, but I would rather look into Func<> and/or Action<>

Example from MSDN:

```
public class GenericFunc
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Instantiate delegate to reference UppercaseString method
      Func<string, string> convertMethod = UppercaseString;
      string name = "Dakota";
      // Use delegate instance to call UppercaseString method
      Console.WriteLine(convertMethod(name));
   }

   private static string UppercaseString(string inputString)
   {
      return inputString.ToUpper();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates.

```
delegate ReturnType YourFunctionDelegate(argType yourArgument);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

For instance, say that the function you want to pass is this:

```
void MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2);
```

You can declare a delegate for it:

```
delegate void MyFunctionDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);
```

You can think of a delegate as a type representing functions with a specific signature.

Now, back to the functions to which you want to pass `MyFunction`. You can do that by specifying another argument taking a delegate `YourFunctionDelegate`.

```
private void settingsYTP(otherArguments, MyFunctionDelegate function) 
{
    // Some code ...

    // Use the delegate function
    function(1, 2);

    // Some other cose...
}
```

Finally, just

```
MyFunctionDelegate functionDelegate = MyFunction;
settingsYTP(otherArguments, functionDelegate);
```

Comment: quite new to delegates, not that much of a briliant programmer could you enlighten me?

Comment: thank you for going through the trouble of writing this but i think ill go with the answer above, seems that i haven't got the right skill to dive into delegates just yet. However do you know any good tutorial s that might help?

Comment: Sure, I think this will do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx